# A question on melting ice

Tags: thermodynamics, radiation, phase-transition

I have a question on melting ice using solar energy. Assuming solar energy transfer in ice obeys Beer's law, i.e.

$$R(z)=R_0e^{-z/d}$$
then the intensity could be expressed by

$$I(z)=\frac{dR}{dz}$$

Assume ice at location $z$ with thickness $dz$, then the solar energyreceived by this volume over time  $t$ could be expressed by

$$\int_{z}^{z+dz}I(z) dz \Delta t$$

to melt ice of this thickness $dz$, the solar energy needed is

$$\lambda \rho dz$$

where $\lambda$ is latent heat of fushion per unit mass and $\rho$ is density of ice, then to see how long is needed to melt ice of thickness $dz$, solve

$$\int_{z}^{z+dz}I(z) dz \Delta t=\lambda \rho dz$$
$$ \Delta t=\frac{\lambda \rho dz}{\int_{z}^{z+dz}I(z) dz}$$
if we take $dz \rightarrow 0$, i.e. trying to find the limit of the right hand side then we'll notice that $\Delta t$ is not $0$ (You can check this).

This seem strange to me since it means that if $t < \Delta t$ then the ice of thickness $dz$ receives energy however no melt happens since it needs at least time $\Delta t $ to melt. So where does the energy go before time $\Delta t$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You used latent heat in your computations as if you were familiar with it., but, correct me if wrong, it seems that you are asking about latent heat itself. Latent heat is the amount of energy needed in a first order phase transition. During the phase transition there is no temperature change. That energy goes on breaking molecular bonds.

Comment: What is R in your first equation?

Comment: @MarcoCiafa Yes during melting temperature of ice remains $0$ degree and if ice of $0$ degree receives solar energy it must be used to melt ice, but as I stated in the question when $dz \rightarrow 0$ the latent heat that used to melt it is not $0$ and when it received energy less then this amount, nothing melts and I'm wondering what this part of energy goes.

Comment: @nasu R_0 is solar energy flux at surface of ice, $W/m^2$

Comment: I don't see why you are integrating over $dz$  if intensity is per unit of area and $dz$ it's just the thikness. I would integrate $I$ wrt $dS$, write the energy needed for melting the ice as $\lambda \epsilon S$ (where $\epsilon$ is the thickness) and, then, take the limit, $S \to 0$. That's just formalism. It will still give a finite $\Delta t$, becuase that's how first order transitions work.

Comment: Again, latent heat is used for melting ice. My simple and best explanation I can give is ''break molecular bonds'' (giving KE to molecules so they can overcome the intermolecular forces). While the energy recived per unit of volume doesn't reaches the latent heat needed, there is no phase transition. This is as far as can't get, thermodynamics is not at all my strenght.

Comment: @MarcoCiafa intensity is a function of $z$ so in order to calculate energy absorbed within a volume of unit area and thickness $dz$ we need to integrate intensity from $z$ to $z+dz$

Comment: It could be a function of anything depending on what you call thinkness and which is the surface which will absorb the energy. Nevermind, does my second comment answer your question or not?

Comment: @MarcoCiafa If you think of melting ice using turbulent energy, assume ice surface receives sensible heat $10 W/m^2$, then redo the calculation $10 \Delta t= \rho \lambda dz$, then here when $dz \rightarrow 0$ we get $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$. However using solar energy $\Delta t  \not \rightarrow 0$.  Here intermolecular forces are overcome by this small sensible heat transfer, different from solar energy from my original question, am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126282/discussion-between-marcociafa-and-maskoff).

Comment: @Maskoff Then what you call "intensity" is an energy density isn't it?

Comment: @nasu yes it's energy per unit volume per unit time